# Replace variable amounts of group

Tags: python, regex

I have the string `"The dog has 12.345 bones"`. I want to match `12.345` and replace its `.` with `XYZ` such that the string becomes `"The dog has 12XYZ345 bones"`. The number could be any valid number which has thousand-dots, so `1`, `456`, `1.000` or `34.234.233`. E.g., `100.00` is not valid. How would I do that?

For internet addresses I used

```
address_pattern = r"(www).([A-Za-z0-9]*)\.(de|com|org)"
re.sub(address_pattern, r"\XYZ\2XYZ\3", text)
```

but the issue is, numbers can be as long as they want, I don't have an exact amount of groups to replace with.

Comment: The `.` is being used as a thousands separator? If you have `1` or `456` these would become `1XYZ` and `456XYZ`?

Comment: No, they would stay the same since they don't have thousands dots.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

```py
import re
regex = r"(?<!\S)\d{1,3}(?:\.\d{3})*(?!\S)"
test_str = "The dog has 12.345 bones"
print(re.sub(regex, lambda m: m.group().replace('.','XYZ'), test_str))
```

**Results**: `The dog has 12XYZ345 bones`

See [Python proof](https://tio.run/##NY1RC4IwFEbf/RW3vbiFDGwFIYU/oh4qhJh5UcG5cTehCH/7sqC3D87hfO4VOjuqvaMYe@MsBSBMCFt8whGI8fKwqk6iat55pmZeFpVctprFmpdfwJKAPtx9oEVn5w6hsS102kO@kWq7g9qO6FniqB8DJ5R@qvkvn8GgTd1oMAUY2ZKdHBeS0A36gTyVaZZerrdUZPB/ECLGDw). Periods are replaced inside matched numbers with `lambda m: m.group().replace('.','XYZ')`.

**EXPRESSION EXPLANATION**

```py
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (?<!                     look behind to see if there is not:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    \S                       non-whitespace (all but \n, \r, \t, \f,
                             and " ")
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of look-behind
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  \d{1,3}                  digits (0-9) (between 1 and 3 times
                           (matching the most amount possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (?:                      group, but do not capture (0 or more times
                           (matching the most amount possible)):
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    \.                       '.'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    \d{3}                    digits (0-9) (3 times)
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  )*                       end of grouping
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (?!                      look ahead to see if there is not:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    \S                       non-whitespace (all but \n, \r, \t, \f,
                             and " ")
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of look-ahead
```

Comment: This looks good, thanks! The lambda function was what I was looking for.

Comment: @MarcelB Yes, both lambda and separate methods can be used as `re.sub` replacements.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to actually replace `.` only when used as a thousands separator, you can do:

```
(?:<\D|^)\d{1,3}(?:\.\d{3})+(?=[^\d.]|$)
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/sN3DYv/1/)

Python demo:

```
import re

txt='''
1
456
1.000
34.234.233
100.00
'''

print(
    re.sub(r'(?:<\D|^)\d{1,3}(?:\.\d{3})+(?=[^\d.]|$)', 
        lambda m: m.group(0).replace('.', 'XYZ'), 
        txt, flags=re.M)
)
```

Prints:

```
1
456
1XYZ000
34XYZ234XYZ233
100.00
```